# How does one run an app from the terminal on a Chromebook?

Tags: terminal, chromebook, google-chrome-os

On my Chromebook, I'm on the Dev channel, Chrome version 72.0.3609.3 on a ASUS C302C.

I'm trying to run an app from the terminal and it's failing.  My question is, how does one run an app from the terminal on a Chromebook?!?  Please note, I'm just using busybox as an example here.  This is a not meant to be a busybox question -- you can substitute that for any other program you download as right now I get the same results with everything.

Here's what I have done:

After putting it on the Dev channel and removing rootfs verification, I open a terminal and type the following:

```
cd ~/Downloads
curl https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.26.2-defconfig-multiarch/busybox-i686 --output busybox
```

I then type: `busybox unzip foo.zip`

```
bash: busybox: command not found.
```

Ooops, I type: `./busybox unzip foo.zip`

```
bash: ./busybox: Permission denied

ls -al busybox
```

It's 644

so I run: `chmod a+x busybox`

...and it's 655 now.  I try to run: `./busybox unzip foo.zip`

and get `bash: ./busybox: Permission denied` again!

Using sudo generates the same errors as well.

I'm stuck.   How does one run an app from the terminal?  Any assistance you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up "developer mode" and "dev channel". There are three+1 channels for Chrome/Chromium: stable/beta/dev and canary.
One can also set a chromebook in "developer mode". This gives the warning at boot time and allows the user to open a shell, set a root password etc.

The following answer assumes that you are talking about "developer mode".

The `~/Downloads` directory is mounted with a `noexec` option. So an executable that you download to it cannot be executed. You can, as root, copy it to a directory like `/usr/local/bin/` so that it can be executed.

Answer (score 1):

The first digit in a file's permissions is for the file's owner (you).  Instead of 6 it should be 7. So do:

`chmod 755 busybox`

I tested busybox in Crosh: it works. However, most people use either [Crouton](https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton) or [Chromebrew](https://github.com/skycocker/chromebrew).  Chromebrew is simpler if you need command line apps only.

Also, your model should get Linux support in the near (?) future.